# WebStorm with VisualStudio 2015 engine

Tags: webstorm, visual-studio-2015

I have both WebStorm and VisualStudio 2015 Community edition.
I want to configure WebStorm to use VisualStudio engine instead of the default Node.js
By word "engine" I mean CMD files from

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\External:
bower.cmd
grunt.cmd
node.cmd
npm.cmd
```

Comment: Suggestion: put the path where those files are located as first in the `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: Have you tried changing the path in "Settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> Node.js and NPM" to point to your Visual Studio path?